# How to solve $\dfrac{x^2-6x+5}{x^2-2x-3} = \dfrac{2-3x}{x^2+3x+3}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Problem: Given $\dfrac{x^2-6x+5}{x^2-2x-3} = \dfrac{2-3x}{x^2+3x+3}$, solve for $x$.

I reduced to $x^4-18x^2-8x+21=0$

And don't see how to solve from here... Please help.

Comment: sorry, I meant x^4−18x^2−8x+21 = 0

Comment: Please edit one of your questions and close the other.

Comment: I closed the other

Comment: The fourth-degree polynomial (which is correct) has no rational roots.

Comment: But is has four real roots.

Comment: Still a really ugly looking closed form... I can post one of the roots if you want...

Comment: Where did you get it? Are you expecting a nice looking closed form solution?

Comment: I need to use high school  algebra to solve this problem and get the exact solutions (4 of them)

Comment: A single typo in a polynomial can turn a simple exercise into a nightmare.  If this was a practice problem in a high-school algebra book, it's likely that's what happened.

Comment: The roots are $\pm\sqrt{3+\alpha}-\frac 12\sqrt{24-4\alpha-\frac 8{\sqrt{3+\alpha}}}$ for $\alpha=\frac 4{\sqrt[3]{5+i\sqrt{39}}}+\sqrt[3]{5+i\sqrt{39}}$ and $\sqrt{3+\alpha}\pm\frac 12\sqrt{24-4\alpha-\frac 8{\sqrt{3+\alpha}}}$